# How to avoid implicit call to parent class's constructor in Java?

Tags: java, ruby

I have this code which prints `"A Tree"` twice and `"An Oak Tree"` once. I guess it is calling `Tree` class's constructor implicitly as `class Oak extends Tree`. Is there anyway, I can avoid calling parent's constructor?

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tree p = new Tree();
        Oak m = new Oak();
    }
}

public class Tree {
    protected String name;

    public Tree() {
        name = "A Tree";
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

public class Oak extends Tree {
    public String name = "An Oak Tree";
    public Oak() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

I naturally tend to compare Java with Ruby due to my little exposure to it. In Ruby, the parent's constructor seem to be called only when child is not having one. So, I am trying to get my basics right.

```
class C
  def initialize
    puts "C class"
  end
end

class D < C
  def initialize
    puts "D class"
  end
end

# class E does not have its own constructor
class E < C
end

C.new #=> C class
D.new #=> D class
E.new #=> C class
```

Comment: Ruby doesn't have constructors, only methods. And what you have there is in no way equivalent to your Java example: in your Java example, *two* constructors are executed, in Ruby that will *never* happen, unless you explicitly call `super`. What you see in Ruby is just simple inheritance. You would see the exact same thing in Java, even if Java *didn't* automatically call the parent constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to avoid an implicit call to a parent's constructor is to make an explicit call to a parent constructor.  You cannot avoid calling a constructor for each class.

BTW You don't need to store the `name` twice.  A simpler approach is to do the following.

```
public class Tree {
    protected String name;

    public Tree() {
        this("A Tree");
    }

    protected Tree(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

public class Oak extends Tree {
    public Oak() {
        super("An Oak Tree");
    }
}
```

In Java, it is assumed there is no sane reason not to call a constructor for a given class.  If you find this is a problem, perhaps you are doing things in your constructor which is more than just construction and has undesirable side effects.

Object construction should be just about initialising the object.  Side effects should be avoided.